# How to 301 Redirect url include particular value

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect with htaccess file any url include My_Value.aspx to my main page

for exmple if there is url like those url:

mydomain.com/blablabla/blabla/My_Value.aspx

or

mydomain.com/MyValue.aspx?id=3343234&type=blabla

or any different way include My_Value.aspx redirect 301 to http://mydomain.com

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/My_Value.aspx http://mydomain.com? [L,R=302,NC]
RewriteRule ^MyValue.aspx http://mydomain.com? [L,R=302,NC]
```

The above should redirect:

```
mydomain.com/blablabla/blabla/My_Value.aspx
mydomain.com/blablabla/blabla/my_value.aspx
mydomain.com/MyValue.aspx?id=3343234&type=blabla
mydomain.com/myvalue.aspx?id=3343234&type=blabla
```

to

```
http://mydomain.com
```

The `NC` flags tells it to ignore the case, which will mean you can use `My_Value.apsx` or `my_value.apsx` or `My_VaLuE.apsx` and it will still redirect.
Change the `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect works.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 My_Value\.aspx$ http://mydomain.com
```

Comment: You may post more explanation

Comment: It is a simple rule that redirects to `http://mydomain.com` with 301 status every time a URL ends with `My_Value.aspx`